# When I'm retrieving blob value from SQLite it gives different value as it is stored in database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor, blob

When I'm retrieving blob value from SQLite it gives different value as it is stored in database. I don't know why this is happening. When I'm using `cursor.getString()`, it gives the same value. But when I use `curser.getBlob()`, it gives different value. Also when I convert `cursor.getString()` value into `bytes[]` using `getBytes()` it again gets converted into different vlaue which is stored in database.

Please tell me the solution as am not able to find why this is happening.

[image]

Comment: post your code to solve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you have used insert query to insert data into sqlite database. 
in my opinion you shud use the following method to insert data also image.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DB_TABLE + "("+ 
               KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + 
               KEY_IMAGE + " BLOB);";

ContentValues cv = new  ContentValues();
cv.put(KEY_NAME,    name);
cv.put(KEY_IMAGE,   image);
database.insert( DB_TABLE, null, cv );
```

Use this method it should work. if not then plz let me know about it.
Gud luck.